# Is the Smallville universe seen in the CW "Crisis" crossover an alternate reality from the Smallville universe we know?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, smallville

I understand that many people consider the **Smallville** world the heroes in CW *Crisis* crossover event to be a "true end" to the series... but there is a lot of evidence against that.

1. *Smallville* ended in 2011, and the epilogue showed that 7 years later in *their* time (2018) Clark and Lois were still working at the *Daily Planet*, childless, and *rushing* to get married. More importantly, he was still Superman.
   So even if we take into account this *could* be the same world, unless it was waaaay further into the future, it would leave barely a year and a half for Clark to give up his powers, have kids with Lois, resign from the *Planet* and move back to the farm. But by all indications, the time/years in all worlds is the same. So right there, the math just doesn't add up.
2. This timeline is elaborated on and reinforced by the *Smallville Season 11* comic series, which maintained Clark retaining his powers and having multiple adventures.
3. In *that* series we have *seen* alternate realities which simultaneously exist alongside the "proper" *Smallville* timeline; Brainiac showed Clark one, Lois ventured to another, and Clark Luthor came from yet another.
4. Current comics show Clark, under the right conditions, wouldn't *need* to give up his abilities to have kids with Lois. And considering his position/destiny role/ responsibility as "the Light to show humanity the way", it's sort of selfish, which we have seen is against his very *nature,* in the show.
5. *Multiple* entities that can see Clark's future in the show (the kid with that power, the Legion of Super Heroes, *Dr. Fate!*) showed Clark's future as "utterly blinding" and him "going on" and telling tales of him doing things that inspired the Universe. Him giving up his abilities would wipe out all of that, especially considering some of the legends the Legion *still* held about him.

This is also especially true considering the ever present threat of Darkseid in that world; not only would it be unwise for Clark to surrender his abilities and leave the Earth vulnerable for a take over, but it would make his family an utter target for the tyrant, and give him *nothing* to defend them with.

So while this would be a sweet little head nod to the *Smallville* fans seeking closure, it doesn't seem exactly likely. My question then is:

**Is this TRULY the same *Smallville* universe we were watching, or more than likely some alternative take on that world?**

Confirmation from the *Smallville* creative team may be the only way to be sure, but anything "officially stated" might help.

Comment: "This is an imaginary story.  But then, aren't they all?"

Comment: We aren't told in what way he gave up the powers. Jor-El did take them from him a few times during the show's run, so the fortress can do it easily, but giving the AI's attitude over the years with its constant "Embrace Your Destiny" shtick I somehow doubt that. Then there are both _blue_ and _gold_ kryptonite. Gold would mean giving them up forever, but blue would be enough to enable them to have kids in this continuity --- it did work for Dax-Ur after all.

Answer (score 3):

As per the official words from Arrowverse part, it takes place after season 11 comics:

> @mguggenheim Ok ok, so I know I asked some questions that can't be answered right now, but I bet many people want to know this one. Will any of the events from the Smallville Season 11 comic book be brought up by Tom in the Crisis? I think that question is harmless, right? : - Julian M. Clarke- [tweet](https://twitter.com/JulianMClarke/status/1180196272726298624?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1180198198838796289&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbatman-news.com%2F2019%2F10%2F05%2Fsmallville-season-11-comic-is-canon-for-crisis-on-infinite-earths%2F)
>
> They won't be directly referenced but we consider the comic to be canon (with one small "off-camera" repurchase of a certain farm). - [Marc Guggenheim](https://twitter.com/mguggenheim/status/1180198198838796289?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1180198198838796289&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbatman-news.com%2F2019%2F10%2F05%2Fsmallville-season-11-comic-is-canon-for-crisis-on-infinite-earths%2F)

But which year it takes place in *Smallville* is kept vague.

Comment: That still doesn't explain the time skip, as you mentioned, _or_ HOW the world became _safe_ enough for Clark to give up his powers. Considering that was a running theme in the show, it seems a bit off. But if they are considering the comic  canon, then there would still be grave danger after its _Continuity_ arc.